# Are these abbreviations common in programming/image processing?

Tags: terminology

I am editing terms that will be used on an user interface of the controller of a vision sensor designed for factory use.

Since there is a restriction of space on the UI, I am trying to abbreviate terms although it seems tricky ..

Are any of the following abbreviations common or do they rather make you confused？Any other suggestions?

- Position-Pos.
- Coordinate - Coord.
- Radius - r
- Circle - CRCL/ Cir./ Circ.
- Deviation - Dev.
- Region - Reg.
- Intersection - Int.
- Reference - Ref.

Comment: Which countries will the device be sold in ? - ie what will be native language / dialect (US English, UK English ?) of the users.

Comment: You would probably achieve better results with symbols for most of these. That do not need to be graphical icons, e.g. “x,y” or “x,y,z” may well indicate either coordinate or position.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this depends on the context: if there's a frame of reference, most would understand "Pos" for "Position". Without a frame of reference (ie the user is not expecting "location-y" information) they probably wouldn't

> Position: Pos

Would likely be understood in a reasonable context, but be wary

> Coordinate: Coord/coords

Would be understood in almost any circumstance

> Radius: r

Would be understood if clearly within the context of "talking about circles", not otherwise

> Circle: CRCL, Cir, Circ

Crcl Would again likely be understood (or rather, would be "worked out") in context, the others probably not. You're only saving two characters, however, and it's probably not worthwhile considering it's not a particularly widespread abbreviation

> Deviation: Dev

Probably not, unless within a very clear context AND a mathematical audience

> Region: Reg

Maybe, but I wouldn't want to rely on it

> Intersection: Int

Almost certainly not. Int almost always refers to Integer within a programming environment

> Reference: Ref

Would usually be understood in most environments